# Can I protect short words from an n-gram filter in Solr?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, n-gram

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021226/search-for-short-words-with-solr) about searching for short words in Solr.  I am wondering if there is another possible solution to a similar problem.  I am using the EdgeNGramFilter with a minGramSize of 3.  I want to protect a specific set of shorter words (two-letter acronyms, mainly) from being ignored, but I'd like to keep that minGramSize of 3 for everything else.  EdgeNGramFilter doesn't support a protected words list.  Is there any filter or setting that makes this possible within a single field type, or will I need to write one?

Or, am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thought hard about this one, but the answer in the other question you mention seems to be the only way. This will be a useful feature for the EdgeNGramFilter though.

For now, you can keep a copy field and a [KeepWordFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.KeepWordFilterFactory) for it with only the acronyms you need. Or if your list of acronyms is not know a priori, use a [LengthFilter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LengthFilterFactory).

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I'll keep this question open for a little while in hopes of other ideas, but I'm thinking you're probably right.