# SOLR eDISMAX product search

Tags: solr, n-gram, edismax

I'm new to SOLR and am implementing it to search our product catalog. I'm creating ngrams and edge ngrams on the brand name, display name and category fields.

I'm using edismax and have qf defined as displayname_nge displayname_ng  category_nge category_ng brandname_nge brandname_ng.

When I search for 'vitamin c' (without the quotes) I get all of the vitamins. If I surround it with quotes then I only get vitamin c. The problem is that I can't always surround the query string with quotes because a person might enter 'chewable vitamin c', or 'vendor x vitamin c'.  I've tried the mm parameter without luck. I've also tried applying different boost levels and still not getting the expected results.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Was there a reason for using only ngrams fields for searching? I'm not sure this is the problem in your case, but you may want to look at your ngrams analysis configuration in schema.xml. One from one of my indexes looks like this:

```
<fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" >
<analyzer type="index">        
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">        
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Though you can see this is actually using the safer `EdgeNGramFilterFactory`, the important thing to note here is `minGramSize="2"`. This means that during the indexing process only grams of at least two characters will be created. The word 'c'? That doesn't get any grams at all. While you could set `minGramSize="1"` and rebuild your index, single character grams are a very bad idea, as your search for 'c' would match against any document with a word that starts with 'c' (or contains the letter 'c' with `NGramFilterFactory`).

If you're currently using NGrams with `minGramSize="2"`, a search for 'ca' would find any documents with any words containing the letters 'ca' consecutively in that order. This may not be exactly what you want, either.

My top suggestion would be to drop the ngrams in favor of a more vanilla Text field. Whether you want to keep the edge-ngrams around for better truncation support is up to you, but I suspect you'll have better luck if the Text field is at least in the mix.

You could also take a look at this question on StackOverflow: ["Can I protect short words from an n-gram filter in Solr?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004758/can-i-protect-short-words-from-an-n-gram-filter-in-solr) if you want to pursue the ngrams further.

Also, you should consider using Solr's built-in analysis tool to figure out where your searches are failing. You choose a field or fieldType, and provide values for what was entered into the index and what is being searched. It will show you how the analysis works against both values so you can see how each string is broken down and why it does or doesn't create matching tokens. The URL for the tool depends on whether you're in a multi-core environment, but if you go to Solr's web interface you should be able to find the `Analysis` link on the left.

**Update:**

Now that I have a little more detail from you and am thinking about it again, the results you're getting are very explainable.

With `minGramSize="1"`, your unquoted search for 'vitamin c' is looking for records with the word 'vitamin' (or a longer word containing 'vitamin'), and the word 'c' (or a longer word containing 'c'). Since most records are likely to have a 'c' somewhere, this is hardly a limiting factor and your results will be very close to or exactly the same as your results for just the word 'vitamin'.

In the *quoted* search for 'vitamin c', the 'c' now has to appear in a word immediately following vitamin, making it a much more useful search, but still not great. You should be able to test this by finding records that have a word following vitamin that isn't a vitamin designation. For example, a record mentioning "vitamin tablets" should be found when searching for "vitamin b" (because there's a 'b' in "tablets"). and a record mentioning "vitamin chart" or "vitamin deficiency" should be found when searching for "vitamin c".

The upshot of this is that I strongly recommend having a set of fields for searching separate from your fields for autocomplete. The NGrams with `minGramSize="1"` are just not going to give you reasonable results for the actual search step.

Comment: This has been a hard problem because the users want the search to be very forgiving yet also accurate. I tried setting the ngram size to 2 but that messed up the type ahead functionality. For now I'm using regex to wrap vitamin in quotes in my code. SOLR 4.8 RegexReplacementFilter will support found group substitutions so I'll move it from code and into the schema definition at that time.

Comment: Forgiving but accurate is an almost universal goal. Perhaps you could use different sets of fields for autocompleting search queries than you're using to supply actual search results. They are at heart two different questions (what the user is typing vs what products match that search). Also, I'm not sure you would need the NGrams in addition to the EdgeNGrams for autocomplete.

Comment: `minGramSize="1"` is pretty standard for autocomplete functionality as far as I know, but you wouldn't want to use that field for your actual search query.

Comment: @whitemtnelf I think I found the explanation for the search behavior your seeing, and added it in an update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use edismax - 'mm', there you can give matching %. if you give 100% it will give you accurate matching. 75% will give you list of vitamin... you can programatically handle % according to your need

Answer (score -2):

You may consider to replace the query keyword this way: "'vitamin c' vitamin c". In such case, records matching 'vitamin c' can get higher score than those matching 'vitamin' and 'c' separately. Your search results will still return all matching records. Please see if this help, and feel free to comment.